# Member is inaccessible due to its protection level error

Tags: c#, .net, csharpcodeprovider

connected within this topic:
[How to connect string from my class to form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15127819/how-to-connect-string-from-my-class-to-form)

im trying to do solutions related to their answers (specifically answer of sir Jeremy) but this error keeps on appearing

> 'KeyWord.KeyWord.keywords' is inaccessible due to its protection level

code for KeyWords.cs:

```
namespace KeyWord
{
    public class KeyWord
    {
        String[] keywords = { "abstract", "as", "etc." };

    }
}
```

code for main.cs

```
// Check whether the token is a keyword. 
var keyboardCls = new KeyWord.KeyWord();
String[] keywords = keyboardCls.keywords;

for (int i = 0; i < keywords.Length; i++)
{
    if (keywords[i] == token)
    {
        // Apply alternative color and font to highlight keyword.        
        rtb.SelectionColor = Color.Blue;
        rtb.SelectionFont = new Font("Courier New", 10, FontStyle.Bold);
        break;
    }
}
```

what should i do?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You need to define `keywords` as public

```
public String[] keywords = { "abstract", "as", "etc." };
```

Currently it is `private` and that is why not accessible outside the class.

[Access Modifiers (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173121.aspx)

> Class members, including nested classes and structs, can be public,
>   protected internal, protected, internal, or private. The access level
>   for class members and struct members, including nested classes and
>   structs, **is private by default**.

Answer (score 6):

Use this code instead:

```
public class KeyWord
    {
        String[] keywords = { "abstract", "as", "etc." };

    }
```

The protection level for variable is `private` by default. A good practice is using property for members in class.

Answer (score 1):

You should make a property for Keywords as follows

```
public String[] Keywords
{
get{return keywords;}
}
```

its a protection violation as variables are private by default

Comment: the difference between this and other answers it that you cannot set the value outside of your class unless you define a `set` method

Answer (score 0):

Try to make the string-array public:

```
public class KeyWord
{
    public String[] keywords = { "abstract", "as", "etc." };

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to define the your class with "public" keyword

Comment: The class already has a public keyword. The arguments are missing this keword, not the class.

Answer (score 0):

Please ensure the constructor is added as with public access specifier. this could be a reason for this kind of error.
Example :

```
Customer() {
this.CustomerId = ++counter;
}
Change it to : 
public Customer() {
this.CustomerId = ++counter;
}
```